# find the ul tag inside header

Tags: magento2, php, theme, html

I need to find the template or layout file that contains this ul tag:

```
<ul class="header links">
    <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="text: new String('Benvenuto, %1!').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
        <span data-bind="html:'Testo di benvenuto predefinito!'"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="o">
    <a href="https://mysiteurl/index.php/customer/account/login/">
        Login    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="https://mysiteurl/index.php/customer/account/create/" >Create an account</a></li></ul>
```

I need only the `<ul>` tag. Where and how to find it?

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer, so it will be useful to another user. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check it from **customer default layout** file.

> [Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can't find `<ul class="header links">` tag in whole magento directory you can find `<li class="greet welcome">` in below path :

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

Actually `<ul>` tags comes from the `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` below is code.

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
          <arguments>
              <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
          </arguments>
 </block>
```

Using above XML magento create HTML tag in container. below is the list of the allowed tag.

```
protected $allowedTags = [
   'aside',
   'dd',
   'div',
   'dl',
   'fieldset',
   'main',
   'nav',
   'header',
   'footer',
   'ol',
   'p',
   'section',
   'table',
   'tfoot',
   'ul',
];
```

You will see it in class `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Container.`

And here, Magento render a container to HTML. You can rewrite it `<ul>` tag (I have no idea how to rewrite or change tag) [Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php#L603)

```
protected function _renderContainer($name)
{
    $html = '';
    $children = $this->getChildNames($name);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $html .= $this->renderElement($child);
    }
    if ($html == '' || !$this->structure->getAttribute($name, Element::CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_TAG)) {
        return $html;
    }
    $htmlId = $this->structure->getAttribute($name, Element::CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_ID);
    if ($htmlId) {
        $htmlId = ' id="' . $htmlId . '"';
    }
    $htmlClass = $this->structure->getAttribute($name, Element::CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_CLASS);
    if ($htmlClass) {
        $htmlClass = ' class="' . $htmlClass . '"';
    }
    $htmlTag = $this->structure->getAttribute($name, Element::CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_TAG);
    $html = sprintf('<%1$s%2$s%3$s>%4$s</%1$s>', $htmlTag, $htmlId, $htmlClass, $html);
    return $html;
}
```

I hope it helps to solve out your issue!